# What would be the complexity of these 2 simple for loops

Tags: java, c, time-complexity

```
for (int i = 0; i < n / 2 + 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
    }
}
```

What complexity would it be for this example and what is the quick calculation for knowing that? **n** is the array length.

Comment: Still `O(n*n)` imho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to explain it is like following:

The outer loop runs nearly half of n times, and for at least **n/2** of those iterations, the inner loop runs at least **n** times. The total number of inner loop iterations is therefore at least **n * n/2** and That's **O(n^2)**

Comment: Your proof is for membership of omega(n^2), not O(n^2). The class O are upper bound of complexity, not lower bound.

Answer (score 4):

Count the number of iterations you do.

- In the first pass of the outer loop you do n cycles of the inner loop
- The second is n - 1
- this continues on until the outer loop `i` is n / 2 and the inner cycles n - n/2 times.

Thus the total number of iterations is:
n + n - 1 + .. + n - n/2 = n * (n/2+1) - (n/2) * (n/2 + 1)/2 = 3 * n * n/8 + 3 * n/4

Thus the complexity function is `3*n*n/8 + 3*n/4`, which is member of O(n^2) (also tetha(n^2))

EDIT: In the calculations I do I use the formula 1+2+3+..+n = n*(n+1)/2, which, at least to me is something I know by heart, but is inferred as a formula by Gauss.

Comment: +1. This is the correct answer (but see mine below as well). Btw., the formula for 1+2+...+n is easy to visualize: Take a square of n times (n+1) tiles and cut it in halves by a staircase diagonal such that you have two "triangles" with 1+2+...+n tiles. The number of tiles in each triangle is half the number of tiles in the square, i.e. n*(n+1)/2. Hence the formula.

Answer (score 1):

When you double `n`, the amount of iterations goes times 4.
When you triple `n`, the amount of iterations goes times 9.
...

=> the complexity is O(n^2).

Comment: That makes the most sense of all answers

Comment: make senses but does not explain why? (e.g. why does the iterations go 4 times if n doubles)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are not wrong, but if you compiled this and tried to measure the execution time for different values of `n`, it is possible that you would get the same result regardless of the value of `n`.

This is because, depending on the optimization settings, the compiler may recognize that nothing happens in these loops which has any effect after they are completed. Thus the loops may be optimized away entirely. See e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/bc9Mzr7db.

Comment: When we speak of time complexity, we usually do programming analysis on pseudocode, irrespective of the language the code fragment is written. Thus, although many modern languages are optimising the code fragment, the analysis should be language agnostic IMHO. Further, maybe the OP simplified his question, removing pieces of code.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev You are right and as noted in my comment, I think your answer is the correct one. My point with this answer is to add a practical perspective. It is not uncommon to be tricked by optimizations when trying to make performance measurements. Besides, I had an urge to mention that strictly speaking "O(1) after compiler optimization" is also a possible answer to the question as stated.